# Remove extension from file when user type it directly in url with htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have rule in `.htaccess` which load file without extension from `file.php` -> `file`. This working great. Question is it possible when user write directly in the URL bar: `example.com/file.php` automatically to load `example.com/file`

Currently htaccess file is simple and looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^file$ /file.php [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the below. Brief comments in the code.

```bash
RewriteEngine On

# Strip .php extension from original request
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s\/(file).php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=302,L]

# Rewrite file back to file.php internally
RewriteRule ^(file)$ /$1.php [L]
```

> To make the redirect permanent and cached by browsers and bots, change 302 to 301.

**Update:** If you'd like to make this more broad, change `(file)` to `(\w+)`, which will match one or more *word* characters, including `a-z`, `0-9` and an underscore/lowline. [Learn more](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z.aspx#WordCharacter).

Comment: You're most welcome. Just a little more insight into this: `THE_REQUEST` *never* changes, and always contains the original request (hence the comment). This prevents redirect loops.

Comment: I must write this for every file or is there a way to be dynamically?